# why is this happening ?(kivyMD,screenmanager)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, kivy, kivymd

this the the first code i wrote using kivyMD in python file for making an demo app for school project basically its a login system app using kivyMD and mysqlconnector now i had a doubt on how to switch screens so i searched and found a way using screen manager now my question is when i execute the python file i get output very neat and clean and everthing is in its place the first code is the .py and second is .kv:

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatIconButton, MDFillRoundFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
import mysql.connector as sql

details = {}
connect = sql.connect(host= 'localhost' ,user= 'root',password = "*****" ,database='courier_service_system' )
sqlcursor = connect.cursor()
sqlcursor.execute("select * from login")
for x in sqlcursor.fetchall():
    x = list(x)
    username, password = x[1], x[2]
    details[username] = password
connect.commit()
sqlcursor.close()
connect.close()

class Courier(MDApp):
    def flip(self):
        print("working")
    def security_check(self,kwargs):
        if self.username.text in details.keys():
            if self.password.text == details[self.username.text]:
                print("voila")
    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen()
        #top toolbar
        self.toolbar = MDToolbar(title = "Courier Service Sytem",)
        self.toolbar.pos_hint = {"top":1}
        self.toolbar.right_action_items = [['rotate-3d-variant',lambda x: self.flip()]]
        screen.add_widget(self.toolbar)
        #logo
        screen.add_widget(Image(source = "courier_design(256256).png",
                                pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.7}))
        #collect user input
        self.username = MDTextField(
            text = "Enter Username",
            halign = "center",
            size_hint = (0.5,0.5),
            pos_hint = {'center_x':0.57,"center_y":0.45},
            font_size = 15)
        screen.add_widget(self.username)
        screen.add_widget(MDLabel(
            text="USERNAME : ",
            font_size=12,
            size_hint=(0.25, 0.05),
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45},
            theme_text_color="Secondary"))
        self.password = MDTextField(
            text="Enter Password",
            halign="center",
            size_hint=(0.5, 0.5),
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.57, "center_y": 0.39},
            font_size=15,
            password = True
        )
        screen.add_widget(self.password)
        screen.add_widget(MDLabel(
            text="PASSWORD : ",
            font_size=12,
            size_hint=(0.25, 0.05),
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.39},
            theme_text_color="Secondary"))
        #convert button
        screen.add_widget(MDFillRoundFlatButton(
            text = "Log in",
            font_size = 12,
            size_hint = (0.25,0.05),
            pos_hint = {'center_x' : 0.5,'center_y' : 0.28},
            on_press = self.security_check
        ))
        screen.add_widget(MDLabel(
            text= "——————— or ———————",
            font_size=8,
            size_hint=(0.25, 0.05),
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.508, 'center_y': 0.23},
            theme_text_color = "Secondary"))
        screen.add_widget(MDFillRoundFlatButton(
            text="Sign in",
            font_size=12,
            size_hint=(0.25, 0.05),
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.18}))

        #UI Widgets go here
        return screen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Courier().run()
```

now this the .kv version i wrote can someone explain why the thing is so messed and also is there a better way to switch:

```
<Tela1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            title : "Courier Service Sytem"
            pos_hint : {"top":1}
        #logo
        Image :
            source : "courier_design(256256).png"
            pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.7}
        #collect user input
        MDTextField :
            text : "Enter Username"
            halign : "center"
            size_hint : (0.5,0.5)
            pos_hint : {'center_x':0.57,"center_y":0.45}
            font_size : 15
        MDLabel :
            text : "USERNAME : "
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25, 0.05)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
            theme_text_color : "Secondary"
        MDTextField :
            text : "Enter Password"
            halign : "center"
            size_hint : (0.5, 0.5)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.57, "center_y": 0.39}
            font_size : 15
        MDLabel:
            text : "PASSWORD : "
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25, 0.05)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.39}
            theme_text_color : "Secondary"
        #convert button
        MDFillRoundFlatButton :
            text : "Log in"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.05)
            pos_hint : {'center_x' : 0.5,'center_y' : 0.28}
            on_press : self.security_che
        MDLabel :
            text : "——————— or ———————"
            font_size : 8
            size_hint : (0.25, 0.05)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.508, 'center_y': 0.23}
            theme_text_color : "Secondary"
        MDFillRoundFlatButton
            text : "Sign in"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25, 0.05)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.18}
```

[using .py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqXaY.png)
.[using.kv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mqyS.png)
thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: In your `.py` version you are adding all the GUI widgets to an `MDScreen`, but in your `.kv` you are adding everything to a `BoxLayout`. The results will be entirely different.

Comment: thanks for the reply can you tell me how should i do that?

Comment: the MDScreen worked but the username and password are still in the wrong place

Comment: Did you duplicate the `size_hint` and `pos_hint` from your `.py` in the `.kv`?

Comment: yes ,I did duplicate the size_hint and pos_hint from .py